# NVIDIA graphics drivers options

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, laptop, hardware

I have DELL inspirion laptop and i have both integrated and non-integrated nvidia 340 series graphics card. When I open additional drivers tab and i have 3 options :

- use NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76 (proprietary, tested)
- using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
- use NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76 (proprietary)

Should I leave settings like this or change something (to improve graphics quality )?

Edit

Output for lspci command

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0652
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GeForce 820M
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: And which driver is selected?

Comment: The middle one, xorg

Comment: You can install a proprietary one. It does not matter which.

Comment: well, when I look at my SYstem settings i get Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile  and i think thats the integrated video card

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: And what is Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu 15, but it was the same on ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install proprietary drivers by running in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

Then you will be able to switch between the integrated and discrete adapters after a reboot.

Comment: It solved the problem , tnx a lot